# change in value of one frequency bin affect FFT and IFFT values of non changing bins

Tags: signal-processing, frequency

I have a 3001x577 matrix. I want to apply a operation to the first 120 samples. I have applied to the first 120 samples which accounts to 20 Hz of frequency. The sampling rate is 2 msec. So I have Fnyq =250hz. Now I have taken out the first 120 samples. I noticed that after applying the filter and replacing it with the older 120 samples, the values of bins greater than 120 has changed after I applied an IFFT . And this is evident on my final result. I got the desired filter result but it ends up changing values of samples which i want untouched.

Can someone explain why change in value of few frequency bins affect the ifft or fft of non changing bins. I am using matlab. And how can i prevent it?

Comment: Could you share your code? That could make it easier for us to better understand what you are doing and where things might go wrong.

Comment: `
  fall2_orig_matrix=cell2mat(fall2_orig);%orignal fft matrix
  slope1=40;
 slopeincr=dt*1000; %in msecs
 for kk=slope1:slopeincr:40
 for  ii = 1:1:nh    %no of columns in matrix
    for j=1:1:r   % no of samples
      ffbin=(250/pad)*j;%250 are nyqsuit freq
     ff=-i*2*pi*(ffbin)*(kk/1000);%chaning slope option
      shifted(j,ii)=ifftshift(exp(ff));  
    end
 end
    Modell{kk}=shifted.*(fall2_orig_matrix);
 end
Model= Modell{kk};
`

Comment: fall2_orig_matrix=cell2mat(fall2_orig);%orignal fft matrix
  slope1=40;
 slopeincr=dt*1000; %in msecs
 for kk=slope1:slopeincr:40
 for  ii = 1:1:nh    %no of columns in matrix
    for j=1:1:r   % no of samples
      ffbin=(250/pad)*j;%250 are nyqsuit freq
     ff=-i*2*pi*(ffbin)*(kk/1000);%chaning slope option
      shifted(j,ii)=ifftshift(exp(ff));  
    end
 end
    Modell{kk}=shifted.*(fall2_orig_matrix);
 end
Model= Modell{kk};

Answer (score 1):

You took part of the spectrum (the first 120 samples), changed this part somehow and transformed the outcome back into the time domain by using an IFFT. It is to be expected that the signal has changed beyond the 120 samples since you manipulated frequency components which will alter all samples in the time domain. Think of it this way: You changed the amplitude (and phase) of 120 sinuses and then expect that the outcome to be limited to a certain time extent. Maybe you can post a new question where you describe what you actually want to achieve instead of the experiment you perform to get the job done.

Comment: Thanks Michael. This is what is happening. I need to apply filter on the first 120 samples(frequency bins.and then append it to the remaining samples. How can i achieve this.The operation i am running is adaptive least square subtraction ofe 1 to 120 hz which accounts to 120 bins in my case. thanks

Comment: I am not sure that is what you are asking but if you want to change only the frequency components of the first 120 bins then keep in mind you need to perform similar (but not the same) changes at the end of your FFT vector, i.e. you would change the last 119 bins to be conjugate complex copies of the 2 to 120 bin. Any real signal in the time domain results in a conjugate complex spectrum.

Comment: Thanks Michael.that's been taken care of.